# Debug C# Metro app on non-networked machine

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to create my first Metro app, in order to debug it and run it, do I need a developer licence? And if my machine is not connected to the web - what can I do? Nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just open Visual Studio 11 Express for Windows 8 or VS 11 Beta and it will get a free license from Microsoft that I believe will be free for a month or so. They have been extending it every month so far. I believe you do need to be online to get it though.